# Run script for 10 times or until it meets the condition

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, for

I have following shell script.

```
 OUTPUT=$(systemctl is-active etcd)
 if [[ $OUTPUT == active ]]; then
       echo "The result is successfull"
   else
       echo "The result is unsuccessfull"
 fi
```

I want to run this script 10 times, for each time it will sleep 10 seconds. 
I was able to achieve this using `for i in {1..10}` loop and then using sleep command.

```
for i in {1..10}; do
   sleep 10
   OUTPUT=$(systemctl is-active etcd)
   if [[ $OUTPUT == active ]]; then
       echo "The result is successfull"
   else
       echo "The result is unsuccessfull"
   fi
done
```

But I want to break the script if it matches the condition during (e.g. 1st or 2nd etc) iteration and don't want to execute next iteration.

I guess I need to implement while loop, but I am not sure how can I add condition and for loop there.

Comment: I'd quote "$OUTPUT" in the *if* statement. It will fail if the variable is empty (and probably if it contains a space).

Comment: A bit off topic, but you can skip capturing the output, and just do `if systemctl -q is-active etcd; then ...`.

Answer (score 7):

The `break` [builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) is used for this.

```
for i in {1..10}; do
   sleep 10
   OUTPUT=$(systemctl is-active etcd)
   if [[ $OUTPUT == active ]]; then
       echo "The result is successful"
       break
   else
       echo "The result is unsuccessful"
   fi
done
```