# Grouping commands of if...then statement, including assignation of variable for shell/bash in a single line

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, assignment

I know the existence of *[while-do-done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1289029/811293)*. Alternatively, I know that I can use *[for-do-done](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518436/117555)*. But, I was trying to test manually using *if-then-else*.

I would to like to execute a command, but doing a shift with addition in each iteration.

```
sh-3.2# currPos=0;stepSize=16;
sh-3.2# hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv /dev/disk0s1 -s $currPos;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos;
00000000  8d 1c 09 48 65 8c 3c 6e  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...He.<n........|
00000010
16
sh-3.2# hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv /dev/disk0s1 -s $currPos;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos;
00000000  8d 1c 09 48 65 8c 3c 6e  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...He.<n........|
00000010
32
sh-3.2# hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv /dev/disk0s1 -s $currPos;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos;
00000000  8d 1c 09 48 65 8c 3c 6e  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...He.<n........|
00000010
48
sh-3.2#
```

As you can see, the `offset` (`-s`) is not taking the updated value of variable `$currPos`. But in the `echo` command the `$currPos` variable is changing (`16`, `32` and `48`)!

**EDIT 1**: According to *Kusalananda* (Thanks a lot!) I fix the first step.

```
sh-3.2# currPos=0;stepSize=16;finalStep=48;
sh-3.2# hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv -s $currPos /dev/disk0s1;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos;
00000000  8d 1c 09 48 65 8c 3c 6e  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...He.<n........|
00000010
16
sh-3.2# hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv -s $currPos /dev/disk0s1;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos;
00000010  bd 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020
32
sh-3.2# hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv -s $currPos /dev/disk0s1;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos;
00000020  4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00  00 f4 01 00 00 00 00 00  |NXSB............|
00000030
48
```

Let's go to use from: https://linuxize.com/post/bash-if-else-statement/
something of: `if`, `then`, `else`, `fi` and (`-eq`, `-gt,` `-ge`, `-lt`, `-le`, `!=`) and `break`.

Trying to use a iterative with `if`, `break`:

```
sh-3.2# currPos=0;stepSize=16;finalStep=48;
sh-3.2# if [ $currPos -le $finalStep ]; then (hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv /dev/disk0s1 -s $currPos;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos;); else break; fi
00000000  8d 1c 09 48 65 8c 3c 6e  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...He.<n........|
00000010
16
sh-3.2# if [ $currPos -le $finalStep ]; then (hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv /dev/disk0s1 -s $currPos;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos;); else break; fi
00000000  8d 1c 09 48 65 8c 3c 6e  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...He.<n........|
00000010
16
sh-3.2# if [ $currPos -le $finalStep ]; then (hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv /dev/disk0s1 -s $currPos;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos;); else break; fi
00000000  8d 1c 09 48 65 8c 3c 6e  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...He.<n........|
00000010
16
```

**`Note`**: I'm grouping inside of `(` and `)` the commands (`hexdump`, `assignation` and `echo`) of the `then` of the `if` statement.

But, in this case, the `echo` is working worst the first case (the value of `$currPos` variable is not changed).

According to this [article](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) I need to use `{` and `}`. But I get:

```
sh-3.2# if [ $currPos -le $finalStep ]; then {hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv -s $currPos /dev/disk0s1;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos;}; else break; fi
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

**How I can do that?, How solve this (the update value of variable is not taken)?**

**EDIT 2** *Stéphane-Chazelas* Helped me! (read comments about `{`  and
 `}`, note the space after of `{` and before of `}` respectively).

```
sh-3.2# currPos=0;stepSize=16;finalStep=48;
sh-3.2# if [ $currPos -le $finalStep ]; then { hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv -s $currPos /dev/disk0s1;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos; }; else break; fi
00000000  8d 1c 09 48 65 8c 3c 6e  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...He.<n........|
00000010
16
sh-3.2# if [ $currPos -le $finalStep ]; then { hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv -s $currPos /dev/disk0s1;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos; }; else break; fi
00000010  bd 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020
32
sh-3.2# if [ $currPos -le $finalStep ]; then { hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv -s $currPos /dev/disk0s1;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos; }; else break; fi
00000020  4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00  00 f4 01 00 00 00 00 00  |NXSB............|
00000030
48
sh-3.2# if [ $currPos -le $finalStep ]; then { hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv -s $currPos /dev/disk0s1;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos; }; else break; fi
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040
64
sh-3.2# if [ $currPos -le $finalStep ]; then { hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv -s $currPos /dev/disk0s1;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos; }; else break; fi
sh-3.2#
```

Testing semi-colons (near to `else break`):

```
sh-3.2# if [ $currPos -le $finalStep ]; then { hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv -s $currPos /dev/disk0s1;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos }; else break; fi
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
sh-3.2# if [ $currPos -le $finalStep ]; then { hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv -s $currPos /dev/disk0s1;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos; }; else break; fi
sh-3.2# if [ $currPos -le $finalStep ]; then { hexdump -n $stepSize -Cv -s $currPos /dev/disk0s1;currPos=$(($currPos + $stepSize));echo $currPos; } else break; fi
sh-3.2#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that option should be specified before operands.  Some GNU tools rearrange the given arguments so that this is the case, for convenience (so that the user doesn't have to think about it), but `hexdump` on non-GNU systems is not one of the tools that do this.

Therefore, use the tools as the synopsis in its manual suggests.  This is from a macOS system (the FreeBSD manual reads the same):

```
hexdump [-bcCdovx] [-e format_string] [-f format_file] [-n length]
        [-s offset] file ...
```

That is, rearrange the command line like so:

```bash
hexdump -n "$stepSize" -Cv -s "$currPos" /dev/disk0s1
```

If you put options after the filenames and you leave the `-n` option out and let `hexdump` continue reading all its input, you would eventually see that it would try to use `-s` and its option argument as filenames to read from:

```
[...]
hexdump: -s: No such file or directory
hexdump: 12: No such file or directory
```

As for the second half of your question:

- The value in `$currPos` is not updated between the invocations of your commands when you use `(...)` because you update it in an explicit subshell, i.e. within parentheses.  There is no way to change the parent environment from within a subshell, and the subshell environment is discarded when it terminates.
- When you use `{ ...; }`, there needs to be a space after `{`.  The `{` is a keyword that introduces a "compound command", i.e. a command made up of several other commands.

  You would typically use a compound command like this in situations where the shell grammar expects a single command, such as a single stage of a pipeline, for example, or to redirect the output of several commands together with a single redirection.

  The use of `{ ...; }` in an `if` statement unnecessary as there may be any number of separate commands between `then` and `else` (or `fi`) in your `if` statement:

  ```bash
  if [ "$currPos" -le "$finalStep" ]; then
      hexdump -n "$stepSize" -Cv -s "$currPos" /dev/disk0s1
      currPos=$((currPos + stepSize))
      printf '%s\n' "$currPos"
  fi
  ```

  Note that `break` is only used to break out of loops.

  On a single line, this becomes

  ```bash
  if [ "$currPos" -le "$finalStep" ]; then hexdump -n "$stepSize" -Cv -s "$currPos" /dev/disk0s1; currPos=$((currPos + stepSize)); printf '%s\n' "$currPos"; fi
  ```