# Search Hexadecimal Sequence from start position until some defined number of bytes of huge Binary File (grep, sed)

Tags: sed, grep, macos, search, binary

In my Mac, I have this binary 'file' `/dev/disk0s1` with `512GB` (Really is a drive or volume according to AFPS of `macOS`) and I need to find this Hexadecimal Sequence `0x41, 0x50, 0x53, 0x42` for `APSB` (in ASCII).

Similarly to `hexdump`, I would like to control the shift (starting point) and the number of bytes to analyze.

Here some related Questions: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18807855/811293) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4180081/811293). Maybe `grep` or `sed` works on `macOS` but I don't know how to use it As my problem.

```
sh-3.2# hexdump -n 4096 -Cv /dev/disk0s1 -s 0
00000000  8d 1c 09 48 65 8c 3c 6e  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...He.<n........|
00000010  bd 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00  00 f4 01 00 00 00 00 00  |NXSB............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  a8 8d 96 da 5a 95 46 e6  |............Z.F.|
00000050  82 3e fb 1e 40 7d 3e 79  16 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.>..@}>y........|
00000060  be 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  10 00 00 00 84 04 00 00  |................|
00000070  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  0a 00 00 00 e2 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000a0  34 1e 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |4...............|
000000b0  00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  02 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000c0  06 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  08 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000d0  0a 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

When the pattern matches I want to know the offset (in hex) from the beginning of the file. The search should stop after the first match.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's easy enough to search. What do you want to do with the result? For example "Does it exist yes/no?" or perhaps "At what offset do I first find it?" or maybe even "Starting at byte offset _X_ and continuing until byte offset _Y_, does it exist and if so where?" Etc.

Comment: Converting the source to hex as shown in your question, instead of converting your search string to binary, will increase the search length by a factor of x5. It also makes it much harder to match where part of your search string is on one "line" and the rest on the next.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found a command using Shift and controlling the number of bytes to analyze. Thinks of this like searching only in snippets/chunks of file (not the entire file).  I can do this using programmatically, using Java/C#, probably that exist using pure bash.
If you found it, please share with me... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like I've already said, it's fairly straightforward to _search_, but what do you want to do when you _find_?

Comment: As I said I look in the snippets of the huge file (each 4096 bytes), with steps of the same size (4096 bytes). I need the Hexadecimal position inside the file. If I found the Sequence, I stop the search printing the position.

Comment: Ah. "_I need the Hexadecimal position inside the file._" - that's the important part. So you want to know the offset.

Comment: `hexdump` on macOS does not allow options after the filename argument, as made clear in my answer to your other question: [Grouping commands of if...then statement, including assignation of variable for shell/bash in a single line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/713638)

Answer (score -3):

'grep' should work. My Linux distro supports binary files. Express the values in octal prefaced by a backslash and a 0.

Well. POSIX will not allow you to specify '-b offset'. If you want to use grep you will have to install it. THIS is 'unix.stackexchange.com' so I regard my instruction as legitimate, and the DOWNVOTING as a PROTEST against the man pages. I (and everyone else) do have other concerns.

Comment: GNU `grep` isn't provided as standard on a Mac

Comment: This answer would benefit from showing an actual example of how to do this.